# Does etherscan api support retrieving ERC-20 Token txns?

Tags: etherscan

I use etherscan api. https://api.etherscan.io/apis

I want to get ERC-20 Token txns (or Token Transfer Events) like this page. https://etherscan.io/address/0x57e7674b1c58a0edce5a62af228ab34f09c00fca#tokentxns

but I only got the following response. This is the same as this page. https://etherscan.io/address/0x57e7674b1c58a0edce5a62af228ab34f09c00fca#internaltx

```
$ curl "https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlistinternal&address=0x57e7674b1c58a0edce5a62af228ab34f09c00fca&apikey=xxx"

{
  "status": "1",
  "message": "OK",
  "result": [
    {
      "blockNumber": "6751220",
      "timeStamp": "1542883826",
      "hash": "0x5e3abc85125b7363ab29f24d1c5962ab83a15de39f697ba85004906eeff8b71a",
      "from": "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2",
      "to": "0x57e7674b1c58a0edce5a62af228ab34f09c00fca",
      "value": "1900000000000000",
      "contractAddress": "",
      "input": "",
      "type": "call",
      "gas": "2300",
      "gasUsed": "0",
      "traceId": "0",
      "isError": "0",
      "errCode": ""
    },
    {
      "blockNumber": "6751254",
      "timeStamp": "1542884443",
      "hash": "0x5119c2d5eae0fdc4a0e000b84231cfb5db075efd30fcca3fabe91d2bbfdc9006",
      "from": "0xb1690c08e213a35ed9bab7b318de14420fb57d8c",
      "to": "0x57e7674b1c58a0edce5a62af228ab34f09c00fca",
      "value": "2418981481482",
      "contractAddress": "",
      "input": "",
      "type": "call",
      "gas": "2300",
      "gasUsed": "0",
      "traceId": "1",
      "isError": "0",
      "errCode": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get ERC-20 Token txns (or Token Transfer Events)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, you need to use the module account, there is an action to get ERC20 events, [Token transactions](https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts)

Hope this helps